# Условие if в sql запросе. Возможно ли?

Tags: php, sql

Есть запрос вида :

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, (SELECT mark FROM table_mark WHERE table_marks.id = table.id && table_marks.par = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id_user"].") AS mark FROM table WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: подзапрос из запроса выше

```
(SELECT mark FROM table_mark WHERE id = table.id && table_marks.par = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id_user"].") AS mark
```

выполнять только если существует `$_SESSION["user"]["id_user"]`

Осуществимо ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж вы строите запрос из PHP, можете там выполнить все необходимые условия. Однако можно и в запросе к этому предикату добавить "and VALUE is not null" (синтаксис Oracle).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, (SELECT mark FROM table_mark WHERE table_marks.id = table.id && (table_marks.par = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id_user"]." && ".$_SESSION["user"]["id_user"]." is not null) AS mark FROM table WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Этим самым вы получите все записи, где значение колонки таблицы соответствует непустому подставляемому значению.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё работает!